# svn allowing me to update code but not commit, how to resolve MKACTIVITY error?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I can update code correctly, but cannot commit code. I get the following error when i try to commit code:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/site/!svn/act/080632f7-e62d-4987-96ce-88852bf86f46'
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
```

How can i resolve this error? i am using ubuntu 10 as my OS

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/q/256993/77535). Is the same that happened to you?, did you find an answer for it?

Check at the Apache logs to see if our error is actually the same.

*I would comment this instead of placing an answer, but haven't got enough points to do so. I'm more like a StackOverflow user*